# drawing on html5 canvas isn't painting

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I having trouble drawing a rectangle on html5 canvas.  I'm calling this function and nothing is showing up.  I know its sort of working because I can add an alert to it and it works just fine.  any ideas or am I just being silly.  the project is at http://tetris.townsendwebdd.com if you want to look at the full code
thank you

```
paintContainer: function(){//doesn't work
    var cont = this.container;
    this.context.fillStyle = cont.color;
    this.context.fillRect(cont.x, cont.y, cont.width, cont.height);
}

paintContainer: function(){//works just fine
            alert('hi');
    var cont = this.container;
    this.context.fillStyle = cont.color;
    this.context.fillRect(cont.x, cont.y, cont.width, cont.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the code from your website, this is due to the fact that the background loads AFTER the fill you are trying to draw has already drawn. Therefore, if you change your code from:

```
background.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    drawTitle();        
}

var b = new Board(context);
```

and instead draw the `Board` inside the `onload`:

```
background.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    drawTitle();    
    var b = new Board(context); 
}
```

You will get the effect you desire. I suggest you create a method that gets called inside the `onload` method that continues your game after the assets have loaded.